# How to write files that are read only for other users and processes on Windows

Tags: windows, file-permissions

I am working on a Windows application written in Java that writes its project specific information and settings in specific project files. I wish that only this application can read and modify the project files and settings and these files can not be read or edited via some text editor by the user or written to by some other application. I was thinking of adding obfuscation to prevent information access but how can i prevent any other user process from writing to the files.

Comment: Its technologically (and logically) impossible, it requires dedicated, tamper-proof hardware with access control. Files are writable by anyone and anything unless it is locked - and it can only be locked if your process keeps running forever. Also : "windows application" and "Java" doesnt make much sense .... you are writing a "JAVA application", those which are made for windows typically use languages native scripting or programming languages like MSVC and the likes.

Comment: @specializt, you can write Java applications that are intended to run on Windows. With platform-specific assumptions, JNI/JNA, etc. It's not recommended to do so, but not unheard of either.

Comment: And even then it will still be a JAVA application which tries to use java libraries which try to use native libraries.

Comment: I guess that distinction is rather pointless to make at this point. They mentioned Java, they asked about Windows. Does it really matter whether it's a Java application running on Windows or a Windows application written in Java? I think not. Nothing says that Windows applications have to be applications written in C or C++ and access Windows APIs without any frameworks in between. Are applications written in C# suddenly CLR applications running on Windows?

Comment: Yes, indeed they are. The fact that the Microsoft CLR is only available for windows is ... kinda sad but it doesnt really matter -- Mono still exists, the .NET runtime basically is platform-independent -- its called "ECMA", apparently. Who is "they", btw?

Answer (score 3):

As long as your application is running, you can just keep the file open in your application. You can specify how other processes can access the file while you have open when opening the file (the default usually is that no one else can write it, though)¹.

However, if your application isn't running all the time that won't work, obviously. The usual way to solve this is to run the application under a separate user account and only give that account permission to modify the files. That sort of thing works for servers and services, of course, but is rather rare for a normal user-facing application, though.

You can employ obfuscation, or store the contents elsewhere as well (e.g. another file in another place, registry, ADS, ...) and try recovering from a mismatch. But fundamentally, barring separate user accounts, you have no way of actually *forbidding* access to a file. Such things cannot be done with process-level granularity on Windows.

---

¹ I'm not sure how much control Java gives you over this, though. A quick look at `FileInputStream` seems to give you absolutely no control over the handle's sharing policy. You can use native code to open the file, though, though I'm not sure right now how to pass that to the usual Java I/O classes. It could be difficult.